# File upload in php not working all of the sudden

Tags: php, file-upload

I am a beginner in php. In order to upload some files, I put the script.php below on a server (hosted by another company) and for more than a year it has been okay for my need.

```
<?php

    $file_path = "";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

All of the sudden this stopped working with the error message below.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uploaded_file in /home/someFolders/script.php on line 5
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uploaded_file in /home/someFolders/script.php on line 6
```

What could have gone wrong and what should I change to make my uploads work again?

Comment: Show the `html` portion.

Comment: That sounds awful. Could please you replace the file with the following and paste the output here after submitting a file `<?php var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman, there is no html portion

Comment: @Terminus, the whole file ?

Comment: Fair enough. Where is the form, from where a user will upload a file?

Comment: Really just want to see the output of the `var_dump`. Replacing it would just be temporary; doesn't *need* to be the whole file but reducing the number of things going on is key to troubleshooting.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman, finally found the issue. Was related to the fact that the file upload limit in the php.ini has been suddenly decreased by my hosting service. The fact that really small files were still being uploaded gave me this hint. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Terminus, finally found the issue. Was related to the fact that the file upload limit in the php.ini has been suddenly decreased by my hosting service. The fact that really small files were still being uploaded gave me this hint. Thank you for your help